# Google play requires api level 31 or higher after update even though google play isn't used

Tags: android, google-play

So I just updated my android studio, Kotlin and Gradle version but for some reason I am getting an error on my target SDK version saying that Google Play requires a higher version?
It seems to me that there is some issue here, because we will never deploy our app to Google Play.

I know for some this might be weird, but this has a proper reason we are building our app for a specific android device/model and this type of device doesn't have Google Play.

So in my opinion since Google Play hasn't been added nor are we adding this to Google Play this error message shouldn't be appearing right?

Any ideas why this error is appearing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It must be enforced by the newest AGP versions.

Comment: Try suppressing the error by adding the following before `targetSdkVersion` declaration: `//noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion`

Comment: Is it mandatory to also update 3rd party dependencies to comply with API 31 requirement? What if the vendor didn't release the supported version?

Comment: @TusharGogna I guess it depends on what the dependency does. If it has functionality that the API 31 blocks or no longer support, then it might be required to update. In case the vendor didn't release a supported version, you could either request support for that version or make a pull request for it with minimal changes to support it. If you can leave it in the current version without any issues, then i guess why not (unless the vendor recommends upgrading of course).

Answer (score 2):

So in the end, I had to update the version nonetheless (after all, it's not a bad thing to already support higher android versions).

As a result I had to go down the rabbit hole of updates trying to fix everything especially since android was giving me a hard time due to newly added protection like permissions no longer accessible to be used. Which was actually the main reason why I didn't want to update in the first place.

I was able to fix most of the issues, only 1 permission issue remains:

```
    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (!hasFocus && PreferenceUtil.getKioskMode()) {
            // Close every kind of system dialog while in kiosk mode
            val closeDialog = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)
            sendBroadcast(closeDialog) /*<!-- error:
 Missing permissions required by intent Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS:
 android.permission.BROADCAST_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS*/
        }
    }
```

So not sure how to solve that issue tho...